# Handling incoming Facebook App Request ID from Playstore android

Tags: android, facebook

My problem is that when user clicks on app request notification on facebook , then  if app is already installed it get and process App "request Id". this is the code

```
Uri intentUri = getIntent().getData();
        if (intentUri != null) {
            String requestIdParam = intentUri.getQueryParameter("request_ids");
            if (requestIdParam != null) {

                String array[] = requestIdParam.split(",");
                requestId = array[0];
                Log.v("Application Request ID***","APP ID: "+requestId);



            }
        }
```

But when app is not already installed on device it take user to playstore and then user click install. in that case I am unable to receive app "requestId".

"requestId" lost in that particular case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is default behaviour.. currently no support in the Facebook SDK for getting that information if the user needs to install the app from the play store.

Comment: it mean its not posible by using facebook sdk :(

Comment: i think you need to add your own functionality to achieve this